# Unary spacing with unicode-math and hyperref

Tags: math-mode, spacing, hyperref, amsmath

I'm using LuaLaTeX 1.13.2 from TeX Live 2021, `unicode-math` 2020-01-31 v0.8q, and `hyperref` 2021-06-07 v7.00m.

Let's start with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2in, paperheight=1.5in, textwidth=1.5in, textheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
-1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
{}-1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This typesets to the document below; the difference in spacing between the two equations is intended:

[image]

Changing the include line to `\usepackage{unicode-math,hyperref}` messes up the spacing of the unary minus. This affects only the first unary symbol in display math, not if the unary appears in parentheses or inline math:

[image]

But changing it to `\usepackage{hyperref,unicode-math}` inserts additional vertical space between the equations. This is usually not an issue because there should be text between the two equations, but it is still strange:

[image]

It seems to be a `unicode-math` problem because neither issue appears when the package list is a permutation of `fontspec` and `hyperref`. The conclusions are unchanged if XeLaTeX is used instead. Are there fixes, and is there a canonical order to include these packages?

Comment: the problem is not unicode-math but amsmath (loaded by unicode-math). And there is not much one can do, load hyperref after unicode math and hide the number with `{-1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\incr@eqnum` as below. Ulrike and I are considering in chat if this would be safe fix for amsmath to do generally

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\incr@eqnum{\ifmmode\mathopen\fi{\refstepcounter{equation}}\let\incr@eqnum\@empty}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
-1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
{}-1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that breaks labels as \@currentlabel is now set inside the mathopen group ;-(

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\refstepcounter{equation}\ifmmode\mathopen{}\fi` ?

Comment: that could work. I will run the tests again (I tried to change it in amsmath ;-))